# Can someone explain this SQL query?

Tags: sql

I just started with SQL and I found this query and just I can't understand it.

SQL>

```
select e.*
    from   employees e
    where (select count(*)
           from   employees x
           where  x.bdate > e.bdate) = 3;
```

the `x.bdate > e.bdate` is always true right? o_O 
can someone explain it please? . thanks

Comment: It selects from employees in intervals skipping every 3 rows ordered by bdate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that `employees.bdate` is unique, then it is getting the fourth largest `bdate` value.  If they are not unique, then it might be getting the first, second, third, or no value at all.

Imagine you have data like this:

```
bdate
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
```

The subquery is calculating the number of rows with a larger bdate:

```
bdate     calc
  1        4
  2        3
  3        2
  4        1
  5        0
```

In this case, it would return "2".  Most dialects of SQL have the `RANK()` function, which does something quite similar.  Also, because there might be duplicate `bdate` values, the query probably does not do what the author really intended.  That would be something more like:

```
select e.*
from   employees e
order by bdate desc
fetch first 1 row only offet 3;
```

Comment: Thanks!  i got it now